# Read file from Application folder while publishing a Click Once application C#

Tags: c#

I have an application in C# where I have to select a file and process it. I use Visual Studio's Publish option to generate a Click Once application . But if I want to bundle the file along with the application and set it as default instead of Open File dialog, where should I place the file? The file is an Excel file

Answer (score 0):

first create a folder to hold your custom files in the project,put your excel file inside that folder using add as link in the dialog box.Mark all files as Copy if newer (Copy to output directory property)and just make sure your build action is content. 
Thats it..

for more reference

[Source 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx)

[Source 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fehc36e.aspx)

Comment: And while reading the file, what will be the path of the directory?

Comment: ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory

Comment: I did that but the excel file has become a DEPLOY file. How to read it as Excel file?